# System.MissingFieldException: 'Field not found: Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty. (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am getting this error when I open the page on iOS however it is working on android perfectly. Could you explain? Thank you.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    GnsportsGameEventListPage1ModelData item = new GnsportsGameEventListPage1ModelData("Test")
    {
         CompetitionId = 1
    };
    modelTeam.AddItem(item);
         
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

[[image: VS editor with exception]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTP8a.jpg)

Comment: Try disabling any code optimizations that you have for iOS (code shrinkers and similar things)

Comment: You are using Core which sits on top of the Operating System (Xamarin, Android) and each have their own kernels.  So you may need to update the kernel or one of the dlls of the application (a GITHUB) may not of been installed (or correct version), or a different version of Core is installed.

Comment: I updated Xamarin.Forms libraries for Android and iOS. It is working well now. Thank you. You saved my day